# How using my MovieClip in other flash projects?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs3

I worked in flash cs3. Have "People.swf"- library MovieClips, they have export for actionscript and first frame. Names classes "Head1"..."Head2" and so on.
How i make create object "Head1" in other flash project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

load your "library.swf" into a new ApplicationDomain within your application and
try something like that:

```
var _name: String = 'Head1';

try {
    var _class: Class = getDefinitionByName( _name ) as Class;
    var _instance: MovieClip = new _class() as MovieClip;

    addChild(_instance);
}
catch (e:Error) {

    trace('Error - Definition could not be found ! ['+ _name +']');
}
```

regards..

Answer (score 0):

Don't want to copy & paste code here. See the useful examples in the official documentation on [ApplicationDomain](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/system/ApplicationDomain.html) class. You can also find documentation on this class in your native language (russian) [here](http://help.adobe.com/ru_RU/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/system/ApplicationDomain.html).